# O time.sleep() com declarações if/else

Tags: python

Olá. Estou com um impasse. O meu objetivo é que se o usuário carregar no enter ou esperar 2 segundos ele inicie o "PowerBIT", mas numa declaração if/else e não sei como fazê-lo. Exemplo:

```
#(...)
elif machine == "" or #tempo:
     if temp >=20:
         print "A iniciar o PowerBIT 1.0..."
         starting_so = time.sleep(float(temp))
#(...)
```

Código completo:

```
    import time

    def text_y():
        with open('Chave de inicialização do SO(não mexer).txt', 'r') as f:
            text = f.readlines()
            return text
        f.close()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        text_z = text_y()

    def ler_reboot_arquivo():
        try:
            with open('reiniciar.txt', 'r') as f:
                leitura = f.readlines()
                return leitura
            f.close()
        except:
            pass

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        reboot = ler_reboot_arquivo()
#====================<<<código de carregamento de dados>>>============================#
    def ler():                                                                        #
        try:                                                                          #   
            with open('maquina virtual 1ªversão-texto inicial.txt', 'r') as f:        #
                linhas = f.readlines()                                                #
                return linhas                                                         #
            f.close()                                                                 #
        except:                                                                       #
            pass                                                                      #
    try:                                                                              #      
        if __name__ == "__main__":                                                    #
            dados = ler()                                                             #
            dados = "".join(str(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for s in dados)  #
    except TypeError:                                                                 # 
        pass                                                                          #
#===========<<<<<código de carregamento de dados>>>>>=================================# 
                                                                                  #===#
    def ler_tempo_boot():                                                         #
        with open('Tempo de boot.txt', 'r') as f:                                 #
            linhas = f.readlines()                                                #
            return linhas                                                         #
        f.close()                                                                 #
        f.closed                                                                  #
    if __name__ == "__main__":                                                    #
        temp = ler_tempo_boot()                                                   #
        temp = "".join(str(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for s in temp)    #=====#
#==============<<<<<código de carregamento de dados>>>>>================================#
    def guardar_password_vm():                                                          #
        try:                                                                            #
            with open('Password VM.txt', 'r') as f:                                     #
                linhas = f.readlines()                                                  #
                return linhas                                                           # 
            f.close()                                                                   #
        except:                                                                         #
            pass                                                                        #
    try:                                                                                #
        if __name__ == "__main__":                                                      #
            writing = guardar_password_vm()                                             #     
            writing = "".join(str(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for s in writing)#
    except TypeError:                                                                   #
        pass                                                                            #
                                                                                        #
#================<<<código de salvação de dados>>>======================================#
    def guardarTempoBoot(times):                                            #===========#
        with open('Tempo de boot.txt', 'r+') as f:                          #
            f.write(str(times))                                             #
            f.seek(0)                                                       #
        f.close()                                                           #
#================<<<código de salvação de dados>>>==========================#
    def reboot_arquivo():
        turn_off = open('reiniciar.txt', 'w')
        turn_off.write(msm)
        turn_off.close()

    def reiniciar_vm():
        try:
            msm = raw_input("Tem a certeza que pretende reiniciar o SO?")
            if msm == "sim" or msm == "si" or msm == "s":
                print "A guardar dados e a encerrar o SO..."      
                import time
                turn_off_so = time.sleep(10)
                while turn_off_so:
                    reboot_arquivo()
                    for f in user_z:
                        f.close()
                        f.closed
                    for f in entrada_z:
                        f.close()
                        f.closed
                    for f in programas_z:
                        f.close()
                        f.closed

            else:
                palavra_passe_os()
        except:
            encerrar = raw_input("Há programas em execução. Tem a certeza que pretende continuar?")
            if encerrar == "sim" or encerrar == "si" or encerrar == "s":
                print " A encerrar o SO..."
                import time
                sem_guardar = time.sleep(10)
                while sem_guardar:
                    for f in user_z:
                        f.close()
                    for f in entrada_z:
                        f.close() 
                    for f in programas_z:
                        f.close()
            else:
                palavra_passe_os()

    def criar_passe_vm():
        passe = raw_input("Escreve uma password nova:")
        save = raw_input("Guardar alterações?")
        if save == "sim" or save == "si" or save == "s".lower():
            nova_passe = open('Password VM.txt', 'w')
            nova_passe.write(passe)
            nova_passe.close()
        else:
            bios()

    def palavra_passe_vm():
        try:
            if(len(writing) > 0):
                passwordvm = raw_input("Palavra-passe:")
                if passwordvm == (str(writing)) :
                    print "Palavra-passe correta."
                else:
                    print "Palavra-passe incorreta."
                    palavra_passe_vm()
        except TypeError:
            pass
    palavra_passe_vm()

#só fechar no encerramento do SO:
    def user_y():
        with open('Utilizadores.txt', 'r') as f:
            user = f.readlines()
            return user

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        user_z = user_y()
        user_z = "".join(str(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for s in user_z)


    def entrada_y():
        with open('Password SO.txt', 'r') as f:
            entrada = f.readlines()
            return entrada

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        entrada_z = entrada_y()
        entrada_z = "".join(str(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for s in entrada_z)

    def programas_y():
        with open('Programas VM.txt', 'r') as f:
            programas = f.readlines()
            return programas

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        programas_z = programas_y()
        programas_z = "".join(str(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for s in programas_z)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def passe_so():
        if (len(entrada_z) > 0):
            passe_so = raw_input("Palavra-passe:")
            if passe_so == (str(entrada_z)):
                pass
            else:
                print "Palavra-passe incorreta. Tente de novo"
                passe_so()

    def palavra_passe_os():
        using = raw_input("")
        if using == "Utilizador" or using == "util" or using == "u" or using == "user":
            passe_so()
        elif using == "quit" or using == "q" or using == "exit" or using == "e":
            try: 
                msm = raw_input("Tem a certeza que pretende encerrar o SO?")
                if msm == "sim" or msm == "si" or msm == "s":
                    print "A guardar dados e a encerrar o SO..."      
                    import time
                    turn_off_so = time.sleep(10)
                    while turn_off_so:
                        for f in user_z:
                            f.close()
                            f.closed
                        for f in entrada_z:
                            f.close()
                            f.closed
                        for f in programas_z:
                            f.close()
                            f.closed
                    quit()
            except:
                encerrar = raw_input("Há programas em execução. Tem a certeza que pretende continuar?")
                if encerrar == "sim" or encerrar == "si" or encerrar == "s":
                    print " A encerrar o SO..."
                    import time
                    sem_guardar = time.sleep(10)
                    while sem_guardar:
                        for f in user_z:
                            f.close()
                        for f in entrada_z:
                            f.close() 
                        for f in programas_z:
                            f.close()
                    arranque()
                else:
                    palavra_passe_os()
        elif using == "r" or using == "reiniciar" or using == "restart":
            reiniciar_vm()
        else:
            palavra_passe_os()

#função que inicia a máquina virtual (função que coopera com a função bios()-> se esta tiver sido indevidamente alterada pelo usuário, esta impede o arranque do SO
    def arranque():
        import sys, time, msvcrt
        timeout = 2
        startTime = time.time()
        inp = None
        if (len(dados) == 0):
            print "\nBem vindo à máquina virtual. Prima ENTER para iniciar o SO ou B para aceder ao menu da BIOS setup utility."
        else:
            print dados
        while True:
            if msvcrt.kbhit():
                inp = msvcrt.getch()
                break
            elif time.time() - startTime > timeout:
                break
        machine = raw_input("")
        if machine == "B".upper():
            print "A iniciar o BIOS..."
            import time
            time.sleep(7)
             #bios===========================================================================================================
            def bios():
                print "------------------ \n"
                print "BIOS setup utility \n"
                print "------------------"
                opcao =raw_input("Está no menu da BIOS. Escolha o que pretende aceder: Informações do sistema(a), Data(b), Avançadas(c), Configurações do SO(d) (escreva quit para voltar ao menu de arranque.) \n")
                if opcao == "Informações do sistema" or opcao == "a".lower():
                    print "--------------"
                    print "Maquina virtual"
                    print "--------------"
                    print "Versão: 1.0v 32bit \n Data da criação: 07/06/14 \n Compatível com Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Unix, Linux, Ubuntu e Mac OS"
                    print "Todos os direitos reservados © 2014"
                    rebobinar = raw_input("")
                    if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
                        bios()
                    else:
                        bios()
                elif opcao == "Data" or opcao == "b".lower():
                    print "--------------"
                    print "Data"
                    print "--------------"
                    from datetime import datetime
                    now = datetime.now()
                    print "Data atual:"
                    print '%s/%s/%s' % (now.year, now.month, now.day)
                    print '%s:%s:%s' % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second)
                    print "Sistema Operativo(simulado): PowerBIT 1.0® \nInterface: Literal (e GUI nas próximas atualizações) \nLinguagem de programação predefinida: Python"
                    try:
                        import win32api
                        path = "C:/"
                        info = win32api.GetVolumeInformation(path)
                        print( "Número da série do disco rígido: = %d" % info[1] )
                    except ImportError:
                        print "Número da série do disco rígido desconhecido"
                    rebobinar = raw_input("")
                    if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
                        bios()
                    else:
                        bios()
                elif opcao == "Avançadas" or opcao == "c".lower():
                    print "--------------"
                    print "Avançadas"
                    print "--------------"
                    configurar = raw_input("Para configurar as defenições da máquina virtual, escreva a password bitwise para aceder(0b10b100b110b100): \n")
                    if configurar == "0b10b100b110b100":
                        print "As opções disponíveis são: \nAlterar a forma de inicialização(a), \nDesinstalar SO(b), \nCriar permissões especiais para a VM(c), \nVer código fonte da VM(d) \nInformações de Hardware(e) "
                        avanced = raw_input("")
                        if avanced == "Alterar a forma de inicialização" or avanced == "a".lower():
                            alterar = raw_input("O que deseja alterar: \nApresentação inicial da VM(a), \nApresentar código de arranque(b)(aviso: qualquer alteração incorreta destes pode instabilizar a VM)?")
                            if alterar == "Apresentação inicial da VM" or alterar == "a".lower():
                                imprima = raw_input("Digite o texto que pretende que o programa imprima no início (sugestão: refira os nomes das teclas que iniciam o SO(ENTER) ou o menu da BIOS(B)):")
                                import os
                                reescrever = os.remove('maquina virtual 1ªversão-texto inicial.txt')
                                restarting = open('maquina virtual 1ªversão-texto inicial.txt', 'w')
                                save = raw_input("Guardar alterações?")
                                if save == "sim" or save == "si" or save == "s".lower():
                                     if (len(imprima) > 0):
                                        restarting.write(imprima)
                                        restarting.close()
                                     else:
                                        print "Não digitou nenhum texto."
                                        bios()
                                else:
                                    print "Não foram guardadas quaisquer alterações(de texto: o ficheiro ficou sem nenhum texto)."
                                rebobinar = raw_input("")
                                if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
                                    bios()
                            elif alterar == "Apresentar código de arranque" or alterar == "b".lower():
                                #código ainda não concluído
                                if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
                                    bios()
                                else:
                                    bios()
                            else:
                                bios()
                        elif avanced == "Desinstalar SO" or avanced == "b".lower():
                            deletar_so = raw_input("Tem mesmo a certeza (atenção: depois não pode restaurar e pode perder dados)?)")
                            if deletar_so == "sim" or deletar_so == "yes":
                                    print "A desinstalar o SO..."
                                    import time
                                    time.sleep(20)
                                #função bitsky_one--> deletar
                                    print "SO desinstalado."
                            else:
                                bios()
                        elif avanced == "Criar permissões especiais para a VM" or avanced == "c".lower():
                            especial = raw_input("As opções disponíveis são: \nColocar password(a) \nEliminar password(b)")
                            if especial == "Colocar password" or especial == "a":
                               criar_passe_vm()
                            elif especial == "Eliminar password" or especial == "b":
                                try:
                                    ter = raw_input("Tem mesmo a certeza?")
                                    if ter == "sim" or ter == "si" or ter == "s".lower():
                                        save = raw_input("Guardar alterações?")
                                        if save == "sim" or save == "si" or save == "s".lower():
                                            import os 
                                            sem_passe = os.remove("Password VM.txt")    
                                        else:
                                            print "Não foram guardadas nenhumas alterações."
                                            bios()
                                    else:
                                        bios()
                                except WindowsError:
                                    print "A palavra passe já foi removida anteriormente."
                                    bios()
                            else:
                                bios()
                        elif avanced == "Informações de Hardware" or avanced == "e":
                            import platform
                            so = platform.system()
                            arq_processador = platform.machine()
                            nome_pc = platform.node()
                            windows = platform.platform()
                            print "Sistema Operacional: %s" % (so)
                            print "Arquitetura do processador: %s" % (arq_processador)
                            print "Nome do computador: %s" % (nome_pc)
                            print "Informações do windows: %s" % (windows)
                        else:
                            bios()
                        rebobinar = raw_input("")
                        if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
                                bios()
                        else:
                            bios()
                    else:
                       bios()
                elif opcao == "quit" or opcao == "Q".upper():
                    arranque()
                elif opcao == "Configurações do SO" or opcao == "d".lower():
                    alteracao = raw_input("As opções disponíveis são: \nModificar o tempo de boot do SO(a) \nFormatar SO(b)")
                    if alteracao == "Modificar o tempo de boot do SO" or alteracao == "a":
                        alterar_boot = raw_input("Insira o tempo que deseja que o SO demore a iniciar:\n")
                        try:
                            alterar_boot = float(alterar_boot)
                        except ValueError or TypeError:
                            print "Digite um número inteiro positivo maior ou igual a 20!"
                            bios()
                        if alterar_boot >= 20:
                            print "Valor de tempo suportado."
                            save = raw_input("Guardar alterações?")
                            if save == "sim" or save == "si" or save == "s".lower():
                                guardarTempoBoot(alterar_boot)
                            rebobinar = raw_input("")
                            if rebobinar == "back" or rebobinar == "b" or rebobinar == "":
                                bios()
                            else:
                                bios()
                    elif alteracao == "Formatar SO" or alteracao == "b":
                       raise None #Só pode ser concluído quando for feito o SO
                    else:
                        bios()
                else:
                    bios()
            bios()
            #bios=============================================================================================================
        elif machine == "" or inp:
            import time
            if temp >=20:
                print "A iniciar o PowerBIT 1.0..."
                starting_so = time.sleep(float(temp))
                while starting_so:
                    text_y()
                    if (str(text_z)) == "def bios(): right (0b10b100b110b100)":
                        pass
                    else:
                        print "ERRO DE PARTIÇÃO: o SO não foi localizado. Poderá estar em falta a Chave correta de inicialização do SO ou pode estar corrompido."
                    try:
                        import os
                        os.remove("reiniciar.txt")
                    except:
                        pass
                    user_y()
                    entrada_y()
                    programas_y()                   
            else:
                time.sleep(30)
                print "A iniciar o PowerBIT 1.0..."
                starting_so = time.sleep(float(temp))
                while starting_so:
                    text_y()
                    if (str(text_z)) == "def bios(): right (0b10b100b110b100)":
                        pass
                    else:
                        print "ERRO DE PARTIÇÃO: o SO não foi localizado. Poderá estar em falta a Chave correta de inicialização do SO ou pode estar corrompido."
                    try:
                        import os
                        os.remove("reiniciar.txt")
                    except:
                        pass
                    user_y()
                    entrada_y()
                    programas_y()                
            def powerbit():
                print "====================================================================="
                print "                       PowerBIT v.1.0"
                print "====================================================================="
                print "Escolha um utilizador:"
                print user_z
                palavra_passe_os()
                print "Bem vindo!"
            powerbit()
        elif machine == "quit" or machine == "exit" or machine == "e" or machine == "q":
            quit()
        else:
            arranque()
    arranque()
```

Desculpem se comentei pouco o código e se o código está desorganizado.
Eu uso o windows 7 e a versão python que utilizo é o python 2.7.6.

Comment: Olá @Henrique, se esta é uma correção, você poderia ter editado a pergunta anterior ou excluído ela, visto que não são desejadas perguntas sem resposta na comunidade ou duplicação desnecessária.

Comment: @Caputo, Eu editei a minha pergunta anterior mas acabei por alterá-la radicalmente. Então criei esta como uma correção da anterior.

Comment: @Caputo, a pergunta anterior foi [debatida no Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1682/o-que-fazer-quando-o-o-p-muda-sua-pergunta).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma vez que estás em Windows o módulo [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> é o adequado para estar atento ao I/O do utilizador de forma a interromper o tempo de espera:

```
def wait_for_user(segundos):

    import msvcrt
    import time

    start = time.time()

    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            msvcrt.getch()
            break
        if time.time() - start > segundos:
            break

        time.sleep(0.2) # "dormir" durante 200 milissegundos (*)
```

<sup>Crédito das soluções para o utilizador @BrendenBrown [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11784277/352449) no SOEN.</sup>

---

## Solução Original

Uma solução fazendo uso do módulo [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> para aguardar 2 segundos mas estar atento ao I/O do utilizador:

## Unix/Linux

```
import sys
from select import select

print "Prima qualquer tecla para continuar ou aguarde 2 segundos..."
timeout = 2
rlist, wlist, xlist = select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)

if rlist:
    print "A iniciar o PowerBIT 1.0..."
else:
    print "Tempo expirou..."
```

## Windows

Para windows o módulo adequado para este efeito é o [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que de igual forma vai estar atento ao I/O do utilizador:

```
import sys, time, msvcrt

timeout = 2
startTime = time.time()
inp = None

print "Prima qualquer tecla para continuar ou aguarde 2 segundos..."
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        inp = msvcrt.getch()
        break
    elif time.time() - startTime > timeout:
        break

    time.sleep(0.2) # "dormir" durante 200 milissegundos (*)

if inp:
    print "A iniciar o PowerBIT 1.0..."
else:
    print "Tempo expirou..."
```

<sup>Crédito das soluções para o utilizador @Bryan [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179750/352449) no SOEN.</sup>

---

(*) Conforme chamada de atenção do [@jsbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23959/o-time-sleep-com-declara%C3%A7%C3%B5es-if-else/23961?noredirect=1#comment45338_23961) a ocupação do CPU dispara de forma comprometedora enquanto o `while True` está em execução.

Para reduzir essa ocupação para valores aceitáveis, podemos utilizar um `time.sleep(x)`.

[Nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10926766/352449) do SOEN o utilizador @gnibbler apresentou alguns testes no sentido de apurar valores de referência:

Teste inicial:

```
import time
while True: time.sleep(0.2)      # 0% CPU
while True: time.sleep(0.02)     # 0% CPU
while True: time.sleep(0.002)    # 0.5% CPU
while True: time.sleep(0.0002)   # 6% CPU
while True: time.sleep(0.00002)  # 18% CPU
```

Teste com trabalho extra no *loop*:

```
import time
while True: range(10000) and None; time.sleep(0.2)      # 1% CPU
while True: range(10000) and None; time.sleep(0.02)     # 15% CPU
while True: range(10000) and None; time.sleep(0.002)    # 60% CPU
while True: range(10000) and None; time.sleep(0.0002)   # 86% CPU
```

Comment: Vou testar o código :)

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta. Infelizmente não deu o pretendido, isto porque quando passam 2 segundos ele continua a não imprimir "A iniciar o PowerBIT 1.0..." e a esperar que o usuário carregue enter.

Comment: Editei a pergunta adicionando também o código-fonte.

Comment: @Henrique Estás a utilizar a cmd ou IDLE ?

Comment: Estou a usar o IDLE.

Comment: @Henrique Pois, não funciona em IDLE, só na cmd prompt! Deves adicionar detalhes dessa natureza à tua pergunta através de tags ou no corpo da mesma... É importante saber o teu ambiente de trabalho para uma solução adequada.

Comment: A mim acontece-me ao contrário: dá no IDLE e não dá no cmd.

Comment: @Henrique Adicionei outra versão que poderá resolver o teu caso!

Comment: Entao depois de criar essa função preciso de chamá-la na declaração elif para funcionar?

Comment: Zuul: cuidado com o loop  `while True:` da solução para Windows. Do jetio que está ai, ele vai usar 100% da CPU - aidna que só por dois segundos - o ideal é deixar uma pausa - pode-se mesmo usar o time.sleep, por 30ms por exemplo, dentro de um loop desses.

Comment: @Zuul, Obrigado ;) Só por curiosidade: seria possível usar threads para o mesmo efeito (tenho pesquisado um pouco sobre threads em python)?